# MongoDB find().count() - SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1

Tags: json, mongodb, count, find, syntax-error

Have a .json data-supplied collection of tweets..

**Looking to count Delete-Requests in Sessions:**

```
db.tweets.find({"delete"}).count()
```

And this syntax is incorrect because `SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1`

Have more `find()` and `count()` operations to perform, but the error is consistent.

This is what a Delete-Request looks like *(where "**…**" is either a series of letters and/or numbers)*:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("…"),
    "delete" : {
        "status" : {
            "id" : NumberLong("…"),
            "user_id" : …,
            "id_str" : "…",
            "user_id_str" : "…"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `find()` function you have to pass an object. You missed the key/value, because `{"delete"}` isn't a valid object.

I think that you want to get the number of documents that have the delete key. For this you have to use `$exists` operator with `true` value.

```
db.tweets.find({ "delete": { $exists: true } }).count();
```

or directly

```
db.tweets.count({ "delete": { $exists: true } });
```

From [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/):

> $exists selects the documents that contain the field if  is true. If  is false, the query only returns the documents that do not contain the field. Documents that contain the field but has the value null are not returned.